# Best way to code a single line if statement

Tags: javascript

So I have been writing in JavaScript for the last 5 years and am all self taught. The one problem I have come across as I meet more and more programmers. I find that I am not always coding things the best way possible.

I have been trying to figure out what is the best way to program a single line if statement in JS. I do not care about readability and the project is not open source, so I am not worried about others adding to it.

How I usually write my statements

```
condition = true;
if (condition)
  runFunction();
else
  runSecondFunction();
```

But I have found that everyone keeps telling me to use the brackets. I have been writing this off because they always throw in the following line as well "It makes it easier to read"

```
condition = true;
if (condition) {
  runFunction();
}else{
  runSecondFunction();
}
```

And lastly someone finally said to me that I should write the if statements to more closely match how they I written in C# which looks like the following

```
condition = true;
if (condition) 
{
  runFunction();
}
else
{
  runSecondFunction();
}
```

And of course there is the shorthand, but I usually only use it for toggling variables like this

```
condition = true;
(condition) ? condition = false : condition = true;
```

but would it be better to use the shorthand for regular if statements as well. For example:

```
condition = true;
(condition) ? runFunction() : runSecondFunction();
```

### So the question is

Out of all of the many ways to write a single line of JavaScript which is the best way to program it to run the fastest. I do not care about readability, so please don't say it is recommend to write it this way or that way because it is easier to read. Please also cite examples of why one way is faster or slower than another.

## TO BE CLEAR

It is not that I don't care about readability is that none of those if statements are hard for me to read, they do make sense to me in all versions. So what some of you may consider hard to read I may not. This is what brings me to my next point, since none of those are hard for me to read, maybe I should write it the best way for JS to handle it.

For example I found that JS takes longer to run

```
counter++;
```

then it does

```
counter = counter + 1;
```

So finally to be clear I don't have a problem to reading any of these and I would just like to know which is best for JS to handle.

Comment: *“I do not care about readability”* This opinion is wrong.

Comment: Focus on readability and maintainability above all else. No one cares about silly syntax tricks when they are trying to debug some subtle behavior or bug 3+ years from now.

Comment: Any optimization is going to be negligible.  Readability is infinitely more important.

Comment: Agreed. Just because a project isn't open source is no reason to write shitty, unreadable code. Even if you work on this project until you die, you will not always remember exactly what every if statement you've ever written does.

Comment: You could benchmark this yourself. Take a timestamp. Loop 1000000 times and evaluate one of the if statements each iteration. Take another timestamp. Compare the time difference. Then, repeat for each type of if statement. Who ever has the lowest time diff, is the winner.

Comment: Agreed with the rest, you have to focus on readability and have code that is maintainable above everything else. Your future self will be grate to you for that, when he'll get back to the code you wrote. And if you're so worried about optimization, there are a lot of compiler from JavaScript to JavaScript that can take care of that. But the source code has to be readable: it's the more reliable documentation you will ever have.

Comment: 1: _"This opinion is wrong."_ Opinions cant be wrong??? 
2: I rebuild from scratch, so I wont be working on this project in three years.
3: Readability is different from person to person, I usually write my single line if statements without the {} so it is easier for me to read that way, but if it was better to use the {} then I would.
4: refer to **3**
5: So just to start everyone statements except @BlaiseSwanwick was about the one thing I asked it not to be?

Comment: @ZER0 Thank you, I do understand that readability is important, I guess I was being to blunt, so I tried to clear it up. I do care about readability, but I don't have a problem reading any of those if statements. So it doesn't personally bother me how it is written. What I mean when I say "I don't care about readability" is I don't care if someone else could read it.

Comment: @WaleedKhan What if he was entering a JS1K competition where every character counts? You presume too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take look at some jsperf tests:

- [braces vs no braces](http://jsperf.com/if-no-braces-vs-braces)
- [ternary vs if](http://jsperf.com/inline-if-test)
- [if vs boolean](http://jsperf.com/if-statement-vs-boolean-and-statement)

They all seem to be relatively equal (aside from the boolean version being slower in the test I just ran), so I would go with whatever you like the look of best.

Comment: I took the liberty to [add 2 cases to the `inline if`test](http://jsperf.com/inline-if-test/2). I'm rather surprised by the results.

Comment: Thank you for putting this together. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your shorthand can be shortened:

Instead of:

```
(condition) ? condition = false : condition = true;
```

Try:

```
condition = condition ? false : true;
var a = condition ? 'conditionTrueValue' : 'conditionFalseValue';
// Or in this case, since you're just toggling the boolean:
condition = !condition;
```

Instead of:

```
(condition) ? runFunction() : runSecondFunction();
```

You can save a few characters like this:

```
(condition ? runFunction : runSecondFunction)();
```

Now, the performance difference on this, if any, is going to be insignificant.

Make your code readable. You'll be glad you did if you have to get back to your code in a year.

Answer (score 0):

I usually get annoyed by convetion to put every curly bracket in seperate line, and I dont like that closing curly bracked has something afterwards. In addition, I dont like when they are not used at all.

This would me by way.

```
condition = true;
if (condition) {
  runFunction();
}
else {
  runSecondFunction();
}
```

When question is about terniary, then I have to say, that I use it only when there are no functions involved in conditions or results.

```
result = (number == 521 : "equal to 521" : "some other number");
```

I care about readability of my code, it matters, when you have file with many thousand lines of code, that looks quite similar - it is hard to debug or upgrade code, if it is unreadable.

Comment: It not that I dont care about readability, It just that none of the methods I have shown are hard for me to read, They all make sense to me. I have never had a problem reading any of them. So the problem became what is the best way to actually write it.

Answer (score 0):

If you 'truely' don't care about readability/maintainability then just write it the way that feel the most comfortable.

From my experience programming, the reason why people recommend using the the braces is really for maintainability, when someone has to add a block of code for the if statement, one argument was that if you type it once, you won't have to remember to insert it when you need a block of code rather than a single statement.

I recommend using the form below because Javascript has some quirks with braces (from memory), I believe it was to do with the concept of closure/functions) certain codes won't run. It caught me by surprised when I was debugging my broken code and then I read up on it but that was a long time ago.

```
if (expression) {
}
```

As for the performance factor, I believe that is more to do with the logic and code that is being executed and not the way you write the `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the type of answer I was looking for!